# Sitecore 9 update 1: when to choose Mongo not SQL for xDB?

Tags: xdb

Can someone suggest when should I choose Mongo and not default SQL for xDB with Sitecore 9 update 1?

Answer (score 4):

You should never choose MongoDB for xDB in Sitecore 9 Update 1, because the only supported xDB provider is SQL (either SQL Server or SQL Azure).

See the [Installation Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/1E934A0DB5534F2CB1D98A0F4000B25C.ashx):

> Sitecore XP 9.0 Update 1 does not currently support MongoDB or Oracle databases for the Experience
>   Database (xDB). Support will be added in future versions of Sitecore.

Comment: Thanks Dmytro. You are right MongoDB is not supported with Sitecore 9. Actually I was thinking it is not supported in Sitecore 9 initial version but with update-1 it is supported and that's why I asked this question.

Comment: It is only supported from Update 2 onwards @S.kazmi

Answer (score 0):

I just referred the Sitecore 9 update 1 installation guide (Installation-Guide-Sitecore-90-Update-1.pdf) which clealy says "Sitecore XP 9.0 Update 1 does not currently support MongoDB or Oracle databases for the Experience Database (xDB). Support will be added in future versions of Sitecore.".